# Who were the parents of Joseph Souser b. 1815 d. 1883 in Pennsylvania?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, birth-records, pennsylvania

My long ongoing brick wall that I have been trying to break down for 15+ years is who the parents of Joseph *?NMN?* Souser b.4/25/1815 (Pennsylvania?) d. 1/7/1883 (Dauphin, PA). Married Emilian Ickes 1835 in Bedford, PA.

[image]
[Find a Grave](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GSln=Souser&GSfn=Joseph&GSbyrel=all&GSdyrel=all&GSob=n&GRid=116247462&df=all&)

This is believed to be him *(date of photograph unknown)*.
[image]

A long running rumor:

> Said to be an orphan, and was raised by someone other than a Souser. He ran away from them at the age of 12, and became a shoemaker's apprentice (where?). Which he then continued to do the rest of his life. The use of the name Souser is not know if it is his actual original name, or an adopted name. He had just always used it. He also believed he had a brother, but never was able to find him, so was not sure. When he ran away he swam across the Susquehanna river it is said..

To date I have done Y-111 and Autosomal DNA tests on several the Sausser's & Sauser's in the area completed or pending  and multiple lines of his descendants and so far not been able to triangulate a either side of his parents clearly.

There are still some Souser & Sauser lines that have not yet been DNA tested which I am working on.. in particular the Catskill, NY Souser line which split up after the American Revolutionary War; the main surviving line in Michigan today.

My closest DNA match is to two Cooper's which I have a 0 & 1 generational GAP on Y-37 (but they have not tested higher) and have not responded to me upgrading their kits and they both originated in New York state and passed to the midwest through this time period. I have no Y-67 or Y-111 matches beyond his direct descendants.

My closest historical leads in the time frame has been the Sausser's in Berks, PA who were tailors and shoemakers and a two of the early child tombstones in the family plot in Bedford, PA are spelled Sausser *(but his marriage record in 1835 in Bedford is Souser)*. The adoption of Joseph Souser [Michael Sausser's children but that has 
not panned out](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/finding-details-of-an-1821-berks-county-pennsylvania-guardian-appointment-of-two)..

For the the Michael Sausser (b.1731) and the two Swiss Sauser / Souser lines have all test I-M253 Haplogroup so far; but Joseph Souser's descendants are all M-269 (R-Z278/CTS12074->R-Y19146 SNP Branch per YFull).

I have so [far found no other adoption / probate records have been found](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6637/is-there-a-place-i-can-search-specifically-by-birth-date-for-a-list-of-people-bo) for a Joseph with the birth date in the area.

His [will](http://interactive.ancestry.com/8802/005534636_00316?pid=507236&backurl=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.ancestry.com%2F%2Fcgi-bin%2Fsse.dll%3Fgss%3Dangs-g%26new%3D1%26rank%3D1%26msT%3D1%26gsfn%3DJoseph%26gsfn_x%3DNP_NN_NIC%26gsln%3DSouser%26gsln_x%3DNP%26MSAV%3D1%26msbdy%3D1815%26cp%3D0%26catbucket%3Drstp%26uidh%3D951%26pcat%3DROOT_CATEGORY%26h%3D507236%26db%3DUSProbatePA%26indiv%3D1%26ml_rpos%3D10&treeid=&personid=&hintid=&usePUB=true) also does not [give any clues on his parentage](http://interactive.ancestry.com/8802/005534636_00316?pid=507236&backurl=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.ancestry.com%2F%2Fcgi-bin%2Fsse.dll%3Fgss%3Dangs-g%26new%3D1%26rank%3D1%26msT%3D1%26gsfn%3DJoseph%26gsfn_x%3DNP_NN_NIC%26gsln%3DSouser%26gsln_x%3DNP%26MSAV%3D1%26msbdy%3D1815%26cp%3D0%26catbucket%3Drstp%26uidh%3D951%26pcat%3DROOT_CATEGORY%26h%3D507236%26db%3DUSProbatePA%26indiv%3D1%26ml_rpos%3D10&treeid=&personid=&hintid=&usePUB=true#?imageId=005534636_00012).

Comment: What does "Joseph ?NMN? Souser" mean? Where does the birth date come from? If it is calculated from the age on the gravestone then I would treat it as highly suspect - such calculated birthdates are notoriously wrong. Also, the DNA info is interesting I think you've missed out some key information that could help in identifying Joseph's parentage through traditional genealogy techniques, e.g. what do all the censuses say, are there other Sousers nearby, what names did he give to his children, naming patterns, etc...

Comment: @Vervet I strongly disagree and you making a lot of incorrect assumptions including to points I address in my question without dumping every detail I know from 20 years of research into the question. All census data & marriage record matches his tombstone as far as dates first appearing in 1835 but no records before 1835 that I can find.  There are no other Sousers in the area and all similar name variants have not panned out via traditional genealogy and why I resorted to extensive DNA testing including from those similar named to prove no connection.

Comment: @vervet NMN means No Middle Name , or no known middle name.

Comment: Sorry, did not intend to offend. I think you'll appreciate it is difficult for someone on here to be able to solve a 20 year old brick wall without knowing where your information comes from. For example, knowing that the birth date is corroborated by multiple contemporary sources would be useful to know.